# extend EC2HardwareBuilder class to set an other size for the boot volume as 10GB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jclouds, brooklyn

I use Apache Brooklyn in combination with jCloud EC2 to create ec2 instances on AWS.

ec2 instance setting:

- region: eu-central-1 (Frankfurt)
- imageId: ami-10d1367f

  - Name: amzn-ami-minimal-hvm-2016.03.0.x86_64-s3
  - RootDeviceType: instance-store
  - VirtualizationType: hvm
- hardwareId: d2x_large

  - vCPU: 4
  - Memory: 30,5 GB
  - Storage: 3x2000 GB

Everytime when I create a ec2 instance the root partition has only 10GB disc space. I found the problem in the jCloud [ECHardwareBuilder]:(https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/apis/ec2/src/main/java/org/jclouds/ec2/compute/domain/EC2HardwareBuilder.java#L731)

```
/**
 * @see InstanceType#D2_XLARGE
 */
public static EC2HardwareBuilder d2_xlarge() {
  return new EC2HardwareBuilder(InstanceType.D2_XLARGE).d2()
    .ram(31232)`enter code here`
    .processors(ImmutableList.of(new Processor(4.0, 3.5)))
    .volumes(ImmutableList.<Volume>of(
      new VolumeBuilder().type(LOCAL).size(10.0f).device("/dev/sda1").bootDevice(true).durable(false).build(),
      new VolumeBuilder().type(LOCAL).size(2000.0f).device("/dev/sdb").bootDevice(false).durable(false).build(),
      new VolumeBuilder().type(LOCAL).size(2000.0f).device("/dev/sdc").bootDevice(false).durable(false).build(),
      new VolumeBuilder().type(LOCAL).size(2000.0f).device("/dev/sdd").bootDevice(false).durable(false).build()))
    .is64Bit(true);
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to create my own class which extends EC2HardwareBuilder, so that I can change the root volume size to 2000?
2. How can inject this class to brooklyn, so that it will be used instead of the old EC2HardwareBuilder class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EC2HardwareBuilder.d2_xlarge` method just represents the defaults for that instance type. It doesn't control what is actually provisioned.

You can see this if you provision manually - under storage, it offers /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, and /dev/sdd. If you try to edit this "storage" section, it only lets you choose the device of /dev/sd{b-m}. It doesn't let you choose /dev/sda1. When I deploy with the defaults, it actually gives me a 2G partition for /dev/xvda1:

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-36 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      2.0G  686M  1.3G  36% /
devtmpfs         15G   72K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm`

When I deploy with Brooklyn using the blueprint below (with brooklyn master), it also gives me a 2G partition for /dev/xvda1:

`location:
  jclouds:aws-ec2:eu-central-1:
    hardwareId: d2.xlarge
    imageId: eu-central-1/ami-10d1367f
services:
- type: org.apache.brooklyn.entity.machine.MachineEntity`

Can you confirm that you are definitely getting 10G rather than 2G? I suspect that size is dependent on the AMI.

From jclouds perspective, the problem is this information is not discoverable through the EC2 api, so was hard-coded within jclouds!

We could add a jclouds feature enhancement for changing which of /dev/sd{b-m} is used (as can be done in the AWS web-console), but that wouldn't solve your problem.

---

As described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html#storage-for-the-root-device, the size limit for a "root device volume" of an Amazon Instance Store-Backed AMI is 10 GiB.

To have a bigger root partition, you could:

- use an EBS-Backed AMI
- try to resize it on-the-fly (but that would actually be a *move* to a different partition, rather than just resizing to the right; for a discussion of this, see https://askubuntu.com/a/728141, which links to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227318)
- work around it: what in `/` needs all the space? can you just mount /dev/sdb to an appropriate directory?

I personally favour the "work around it" approach (assuming EBS-Backed is not right for you).

---

For future reference, if you did want to override the behaviour of methods like EC2HardwareBuilder.d2_xlarge, then unfortunately you can't! These are static methods. You'd have to build a jar with your own version of that class (compiled against the right version of jclouds of course), and put it in `$BROOKLYN_HOME./lib/patch/`.

Usually, jclouds is extremely good for allowing things to be overridden and customized by configuring things in guice (to change the dependencies that are injected), but unfortunately not here.

If you did want to use guice, you might be able to bind a different implementation of the entire [`EC2HardwareSupplier`](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/40f31786c59e10f8ea74c2bf4463954361d5f68e/providers/aws-ec2/src/main/java/org/jclouds/aws/ec2/compute/config/AWSEC2ComputeServiceContextModule.java#L79-L79) (to thus avoid the static calls), but we'd need to be very careful that nothing else was making calls to these static methods as well.

Comment: Aled I can confirm that I only get 2 GB. Sorry I also tested this blueprint with a Redhat 6.6 AMI, with this AMI the Root Volume size was 10 GB. I will try the MachineLocationCustomizer to partition and mount the other Volumes in the provisioning phase.

Comment: I use the preInstall Method of the Java Entities to solve this issue. I created a new Config Key to define how brooklyn has to mount machines. In the preInstall brooklyn configures the fstab entries, partition and format the volumes, also it moves the existing data from the root device to the new volumes. After that I restart the machine and run a wait condition on brooklyns site. This works fine for me. Thanks Aled